# Using VBA Autofilter to exclude all values between two numbers

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

For some data with numbers only, I would like to filter keeping data <-1 or >1.

I have seen a lot of topics about excluding specific values, but it doesn't match here as my values can be infinite.

I tried this code:

```
length = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2:$W$" & length).AutoFilter _
    Field:=19, _
    Criteria1:="<-1", _
    Operator:=x1Or, _
    Criteria2:=">1"
```

But the error message "AutoFilter method of Range class failed" pops up. I tried also with x1And operator, but same problem.

When trying this part only:

```
length = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2:$W$" & length).AutoFilter _
    Field:=19, _
    Criteria1:="<-1"
```

It works perfectly. So I guess there is no problem with my "length" variable or my range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped the code.
x1Or   to xlOr

Comment: Stupid mistake from me...
Thanks for your help here.